# If string contains in case statement

Tags: string, bash, shell, switch-statement, substring

I'm looking to provide a case statement based on whether a substring is within a filename.

## Example Input

mysql_dumps/tpmysqldump-tps_dev_russell_development-information_schema-2014-03-26.sql

## Code

```
    case $DUMPFILE in
         *"tpdata"*)
             database="tpdata";;
         *"tpmrbs"*)
             database="tpmrbs";;
         *"information_schema"*)
             database="information_schema";;
         *"performance_schema"*)
             database="performance_schema";;
         *)
             echo "INVALID FILE";;
    esac
```

Answer (score 23):

How do you initialize $DUMPFILE? If I run the following, the output is `information_schema`, which is what I expected...

```
#!/bin/bash
DUMPFILE=mysql_dumps/tpmysqldump-tps_dev_russell_development-information_schema-2014-03-26.sql
case $DUMPFILE in
    *"tpdata"*)
        database="tpdata";;
    *"tpmrbs"*)
        database="tpmrbs";;
    *"information_schema"*)
        database="information_schema";;
    *"performance_schema"*)
        database="performance_schema";;
    *)
        echo "INVALID FILE";;
esac
echo $database
```

Comment: Sorry I was an absolute tard ended up calling the wrong variable name so mybad.

Comment: That's ok, you're problem was solved, that's all that matters ;-)

Comment: @user2373636, if your question is no longer relevant, feel free to delete it. It's unlikely to help others in the future.

Comment: @user2373636 don't be tempted to delete the question. It is really helpful in that it is the first that comes up when you want to verify is sub-string case is at all possible.